# Does google analytics track all folders?

Tags: google-analytics

My website is build using coldfusion CFM.

It is a News Website.

Whenever we publish a new aricle online it creates automatically a new folder with the title of the article.

**My question is :**

Right now we have more than 4000 folders in the FTP where the website is hosted. Does this affect google analytics performance? I believe that we must be receiving more hits than google analytics shows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics tracks any html page that renders with its javascript tracking code inserted in it.  See the tutorial here:  http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55488

You can go to one of your pages and view the source code with your browser.  If you do not see that javascript on your page then Google Analytics is not tracking that page.

Comment: To add to this, the browser also has to support javascript. Just because its rendered on the page does not ensure it will get fired.

Answer (score 0):

GA should be tracking any page that has the javascript snippet on it and working without errors.  When you publish a new article, is the GA javascript included on the page (i.e. part of the article template)?

There may be some some limitation on the number of hits free GA will log, but I am not aware of it.  If there are javascript errors on any pages, that could prevent GA from functioning properly.